# vscode multi-root workspace: specifying python path in env files

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have the following folder structure.  Project1 and Project2 are part of a multi-root workspace.
[image]

I will be developing on windows, but running on linux.  so i would like like to keep different environment files (.env and .env_linux), and load them based on the OS running under. The .env file looks like this:

```
PYTHONPATH=./src:./src/utils:./src/app:./src/services
```

My launch.json file looks like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Run App",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder:project1}/src/app/app.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "windows": {
                "envFile": "${workspaceFolder:project1}/.env"
            },
            "linux": {
                "envFile": "${workspaceFolder:project1}/.env_linux"
            }               
        }
    ]
}
```

The code in app.py looks like below - just one line trying to import the utils module:

```
from utils import utils
```

When the code runs, at the above line I get the error "No module named 'utils'"

So i next added the following to my settings.json:

```
"terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
    "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder:project1}/.env",
},
"terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
    "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder:project1}/.env_linux",
},
```

This did not solve the problem.  I figured that this env file approach just isnt going to work and then added the PYTHONPATH to the settings.json as seen below, but i still get the same error:

```
"terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
    "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder:project1}/.env",
    "python.pythonPath":"${workspaceFolder:project1}/src:${workspaceFolder:project1}/src/app:${workspaceFolder:project1}/utils",
    "PYTHONPATH":"${workspaceFolder:project1}/src:${workspaceFolder:project1}/src/app:${workspaceFolder:project1}/utils",
},
```

Still the same error.  I also tried changing the .env file to reference the absolute path to no avail.  **What am i doing wrong???**

It's interesting to note that pylance is able to find the packages/modules when editing. just at run time i get that error.

Comment: I have to remind you that different paths are used in PYTHONPATH by **;** instead of **:**

Comment: is that the case for .env files also?  windows uses ':', linux uses ';'..or do i have that backwards?

Comment: just tried changing my env file for windows to ';' and that seems to have been the problem.  @MingJie-MSFT  can you have a look at the setting.json i posted - does that make sense to you as far as conditionally setting the python path (for pylance/editing as opposed to runtime) depending on the OS im running in?  can the .env file be used in such a manner for multi-root workspaces?

Comment: If you want interpreter to read the env file, you are more likely to use `launch.json` for debugging than to compile and run it directly. Or you can use `import os
from pathlib import Path
from dotenv import find_dotenv, load_dotenv

env_path = Path(".") / ".env"
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path, verbose=True)` if you need.

Comment: thank you..i'd rather not do it in code...configuration in this case is preferred.  it's a bit confusing or not clear whether the OS specific settings in settings.json actually do anything w/ regards to the .env and .env_linux file though.  will have to test it out more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the initial problem,

We use `;` to split environment variables instead of `:`.